# Joomla drop down turns listings into color blue

Tags: php, javascript, joomla

I have a test site in which I have a problem, It's a realty listing site, I have some results and a drop down below them to arrange the amount of results per page, but every time I select any number out of the drop down menu the results turn blue.

Please help this is the link: http://realesta-cp68.webjoomla.es/

After the first 8 listings I have the drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you change the drop down you are setting the opacity of your "rpl_plist_container" div

in function page_change(post_string) you have:

```
jQuery("#rpl_plist_container").fadeTo(300,.4);
```

the second parameter is setting the opacity, if you don't want it you can just use:

```
 jQuery("#rpl_plist_container").fadeTo(300);
```

more info: http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/